# Elements not visible on page

Tags: javascript, css

I moved a page from my old site to my new one, and cannot for the life of me figure out why the CSS isn't working.

https://ericaheinz.com/art/turrell/

It should have 5 concentric white ovals in the middle. I've inspected everything, the divs and CSS are there but they won't show up.

Here's the JS/CSS/HTML

```js
// color looping 
// http://forrst.com/posts/Endlessly_Looping_Background_Color_jQuery_Functi-ey7

var colors = new Array('#077bf4', '#9554d6', '#e62e5c', '#ff9466', '#CCCCCC', '#ffbe0a', '#46b3f2', '#70dab3', '#af93af', '#e51717', '#ffd1d9');
var color_index = 0;
var interval = 3000;

function bg_color_tween() {
    $('body').animate({ backgroundColor: colors[color_index] }, interval, 'linear', function() {
        if(color_index === colors.length) { color_index = 0; }
        else { color_index++; }
        bg_color_tween();
    });
}

// rotation

$(document).ready(function() {
    bg_color_tween();
    $('.turrell').each(function(){
        var r=Math.floor(Math.random()*90);
        $('.carton').css({
            '-moz-transform':'rotate('+r+'deg)',
            '-webkit-transform':'rotate('+r+'deg)',
            'transform':'rotate('+r+'deg)'
        });
        var t=Math.floor(Math.random()*10)+2;
        var l=Math.floor(Math.random()*7)+3;
        $('.egg').css({
            'top':t+'%',
            'left':l+'%'
        });
    });
});
```

```css
.carton {
  height: 95%;
  width: 90%;
  margin-left: 10%;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
  z-index: -10;
}

.egg {
  height: 76%;
  width: 80%;
  position: relative;
  top: 12%;
  left: 10%;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4);
  -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 0 40px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4);
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 40px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4);
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 40px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4);
  color: #FFF;
}

.art-caption {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 20px;
    left: 3.5%;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    font-size: 11px;
    line-height: 13px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
  }
    .art-caption a {
        color: #FFF;
        opacity: .3;
        transition: all 0.25s ease-in-out;
    }
    .art-caption a:hover {
        opacity: .8;
    }
```

```html
  <body class="turrell">

            
    <div class="container">

    <div class="carton">
        <div class="egg">
            <div class="egg">
                <div class="egg">
                    <div class="egg">
                        <div class="egg">
                            <!-- THE LIGHT -->
                        </div> 
                    </div> 
                </div> 
            </div> 
        </div>
    </div>

  <h6 class="art-caption"><a href="http://www.guggenheim.org/new-york/exhibitions/past/exhibit/4819" target="_blank">Homage to <em>Aten Reign</em> by James Turrell</a></h6>

</div>

          
              
  </body>
```

Comment: Please can you post part of code which is not working now? Did you try anything to solve that?

Comment: Sure, tho there's not much to see, I thought view source would be enough. I'll paste above. Yes I've tried to change all the CSS variables I could, I don't know what else to try.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're missing "height" attributes in `html`, `body` and `.container` div. If you inspect, they had height `0` which simply do not display them.

If i added `height: 100%` to all of them, this is what i saw:

[image]